# The pattern of accepting 5 strings from text type input using regularExpression

Tags: c#, regex

I want a template in regularExpression c# that accepts the input of only five words "زیردیپلم" or "دیپلم" or "کارشناسی" or "کارشناسی ارشد" or "دکترا" .

Comment: `(word1|word2|word3|word4)` ?!? - https://regex101.com/r/4Hgi6R/1

Comment: You say you want a "template". A different approach? What about a whitelist? You create an array of the allowed words and then check if `allowedWords.Contains(input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `|` (Pipe character) which is a logical OR (also known as *choice*, *alternation* or *set union* according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended)) in RegEx. So you could use the following:

```cs
var input = "کارشناسی ارشد";
var pattern = @"^(زیردیپلم|دیپلم|کارشناسی|کارشناسی ارشد|دکترا)$";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(input)); // True
```

It's hard to tell with the arabic characters but there are 4 `|` characters separating the individual words in the `pattern`.